# Is this homebrew Crococow a CR of 3?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, cr-calculation

I'd like answers to detail why the CR proposed is the right one. Specifically are the **HP** and **Attacks** combination suitable for CR of 3?

> With the body of a cow and the head of a crocodile, the Crococow is a fearsome predator that lives near large sweet water reservoirs. Its mouth is wider and shorter than a crocodiles but bares the same V shape. It has 2 large cow horns protruding from its head that allow it to charge on land but not swim close to the surface undetected. Its skin is covered in scales and is naturally very tough. Its front legs are bigger than its rear legs as well as his front hooves. It often charges prey on land, that came to drink from the body of water it lives around, grabbing it with its mouth then backing with its strong front legs dragging its prey underwater. It lives in small herds of up to 20 items.
> A Crococow does not produce milk and do lay eggs.
>
> #### Crococow
>
> *Large beast, unaligned*
>
> ---
>
> **AC:** 13 (natural armor)
>
> **HP:** 6d8+6 (33)
>
> **Speed:** 30 ft., swim 10 ft.
>
> ---
>
> | STR | DEX | CON | INT | WIS | CHA |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 16 (+3) | 19 (+4) | 14 (+2) | 10 (+0) | 15 (+2) | 11 (+0) |
>
> ---
>
> **Senses:** passive perception 10
>
> **Languages:** --
>
> **Challenge** 3 (700 XP)
>
> ---
>
> **Charge:**  If the cow moves at least 20 feet straight toward a target and then hits it with a gore attack on the same turn, the target takes an extra 7 (2d6) piercing damage.
>
> **Hold Breath:** The Crococow can hold its breath for 15 minutes.
>
> #### Actions
>
> ---
>
> ***Gore.*** *Melee Weapon Attack:* +6 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. *Hit:* 7 (1d6 + 4) piercing damage.
>
> ***Bite.*** *Melee Weapon Attack:* +6 to hit, reach 5 ft., one creature. *Hit:* (1d10 + 4) piercing damage. The target is grappled (escape DC 15). Until this grapple ends, the target is restrained, and the crocodile can't bite another target.

Comment: Minor note: What romance languages would call "sweet" water in English we typically call "fresh" water.

Comment: @Kirt I think I'd be rather fond of [Sweetwater](https://www.sweetwaterbrew.com/) reservoirs.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov makes me think of pools of kool-aid

Comment: INT 10? That is one smart cow!

Comment: Should probably be a Monstrosity rather than a Beast, like most other chimeric monsters.

Answer (score 5):

#### Defensive Challenge Rating: 1/8

Defensive Challenge Rating is calculated like so:

> Read down the Hit Points column of the Monster Statistics by Challenge Rating table until you find your monster’s hit points. Then look across and note the challenge rating suggested for a monster with those hit points.
>
> Now look at the Armor Class suggested for a monster of that challenge rating. If your monster’s AC is at least two points higher or lower than that number, adjust the challenge rating suggested by its hit points up or down by 1 for every 2 points of difference.

AC 13 and 33 hit points corresponds to DCR 1/8.

#### Offensive Challenge Rating: 3

Offensive challenge rating is calculated like so:

> Read down the Damage/Round column of the Monster Statistics by Challenge Rating table until you find your monster’s damage output per round. Then look across and note the challenge rating suggested for a monster that deals that much damage.
>
> Now look at the attack bonus suggested for a monster of that challenge rating. If your monster’s attack bonus is at least two points higher or lower than that number, adjust the challenge rating suggested by its damage output up or down by 1 for every 2 points of difference.

I used the gore attack with the charge damage, so this may be a bit generous, but at 15 damage and +6 to hit, it shakes out to an OCR of 3.

#### Total Challenge Rating: 1.5625 (2)

The last step is to average the OCR and DCR and round to the nearest CR, so by the book, this is a CR 2 monster, which I think is pretty generous. I assumed you get the Charge bonus to the gore attack every turn, so I am probably over estimating the OCR a bit.

Comment: So to change it to CR 3 I'd have to increase HP to 8d12+10 (62)?
It seems a bit much, what do you think?

Comment: CR 3 with AC 13 corresponds to 101-115 hit points.

Comment: But that's the max right? not the average

Comment: No, that's 101-115 actual hit points.

Comment: Recall that two CR 3 monsters is considered a deadly encounter for *an entire party* of level three characters